# Illustrator: Making Round Corners "Real"?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I've drawn a square, and I've use the "Round Corners" effect to give that square... well, round corners. Thing like a modern day app icon.

The problem is, I want to now manipulate this shape. But I can't because it's technically still a square with an applied effect. I want to render the round corners so it's actual points and lines that I can mess around with. But I can't figure out how to do this. And I'm not sure what the right term is to describe what I'm trying to do, so it's hard to google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the shape.. then, from the menu...choose `Object > Expand Appearance`

This will "bake in" the effect.

<sub>(The terminology for Illustrator is "expand" - which refers to making a "live" effect no longer "live" and committing it to the path/shape.)</sub>

Comment: Thanks! Simple enough but talk about hidden in plain sight.